# ZXing.Net.Mobile : Using GenericMultipleBarcodeReader for scanning Multiple barcodes

Tags: xamarin.android, zxing

I am new to ZXing.net library and I am trying to use it to read multiple barcodes(for now it is 3 barcodes) in one go, I got to know that I need to use the feature, GenericMultipleBarcodeReader. Has anyone tried that and could possibly share some sample code?

I tried to use ScanContinuously and I don't think it suits my purpose of scanning in one go. Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is here :

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

The Github example code has all you might need.